# Group items in while loop

Tags: php, html

I want to add some markup in the while loop, so that each three items are wrapped in a `<ul>` and each of the `ul` should be wrapped in a `div`. There can be maximum 6 items, and I want to get following output:

```
<div class="one">
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>   
</div>

<div class="two">
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

I am trying following code:

```
<div class="one">
    <ul>    
    <?php 
        $i = 0 ; 
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();  
            $i++; ?>            

            <li>...</li>    

            <?php
                if ($i === 3){
                    echo "</ul></div><div class='two'><ul>";
                    $right_div = true;
                }           
            ?>
        } 
        if ($right_div){
                </ul></div>
            <?php } ?>      
?>
```

It works fine if there are at least 3 items, but if there are less than 3, then breaks the code as it does not close the ul and div.

It is important to use the **while loop** because its part of a WordPress theme which uses the while loop to get the posts.

Comment: *“It is important to use the while loop because its part of a theme.”* I don't see how that works. Why does it matter what kind of loop you use?

Comment: Need the code you are using in your condition.

Comment: @WaleedKhan I edited the question. Its a WordPress theme which uses the while loop to get the posts, that's why I said.

Comment: You can still do `for ($i = 0; have_posts(); $i++) { ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure I get it, but I think the problem is:

```
        if ($right_div){
            </ul></div>
        <?php } ?>
```

That should not be a condition, that should be always printed.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're saying you want to 
group things in group of 3's, but if you have 11 items or something
like that it breaks. If that's the case, then on the last iteration
of the while loop you should close the ul and div elements.

Like so:

```
if(condition){
     echo "</ul></div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking reference from http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/have_posts

```
   function more_posts() {
      global $wp_query;
      return $wp_query->current_post + 1 < $wp_query->post_count;
   }

   if (!more_posts()){
       echo "</ul></div><div class='two'><ul>";
       $right_div = true;
   }
```

Oh and i am not a wordpress guy :P